# Legend values, with colors and size ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I have been struggling with the legend format in this particular case and I I wasn't able to find a solution.

I have a data of 96 obs and 3 variables (wd, ws and manganese). I have represented in a polar plot all the variables as I wanted but I can not change the values of the legend. I want to change the size, color and the value, insted of 1000, 2000, 3000 and 4000. When I try to add breaks the legend is divided by colors and size.

This is the actual representation with the code:

[Actual Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3ZZy.png)

```
plot.new()
ggplot(test, aes(x = wd, y = ws, fill = manganese, size = manganese)) +
coord_polar() +
geom_point(shape = 21, show.legend = TRUE) +
scale_size(range = c(3,12)) +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("blue", "yellow", "red"),
                   space = "Lab",
                   guide = "legend",
                   values = scales::rescale(c(50,150,4000))) +
scale_x_continuous(limits= c(0,360),
                 breaks= c(0, 90, 180, 270), 
                 labels = c("N","E","S","W")) +
theme_minimal() +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5))
```

I want the same legend but be able to change the values. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

try this along with your code

```
scale_color_manual(labels = c("............"), values = c("blue", "red"....))
```

new names in label

Comment: Thank you for your answer, finally I got it adding labels and breaks to the scale_size and the same labels and breaks to the scale fill gradient.

Comment: The OP doesn't use `color` in the plot, so advising the use of `scale_color_manual` doesn't seem that useful.  Maybe change your answer to show using `labels` in a `fill` or `size` scale?